# User selects nodes for a custom view (DRUPAL)

Tags: drupal, tags, view, custom-view, selectnodes

all, I hope you can either help me, or direct me the the easy-to-find-in-retrospect answer which is already out there.

I have had two drupal RFPs in the past month where the admins maintains content, but wants users to be able to mark nodes for viewing later in their own custom view.

in both cases, the user should be logged in, and the selections that they make should be associated with their account.

example:  There is an event calendar where the user may select events that they wish to attend.  at a later time, the user may go to a "my events" page and see their pesonal schedule.

a slightly more complex example would be where a user could select images from a portfolio to be later outputted to a custom pdf - in this case the user might want several portfolios.

The only (very clumsy seeming) solution I could come up with involved a hack whereby selecting a node would trigger a some code that added a tag to the node that was the user's name.  then later an view-with-argument could be used to call only nodes with that tag.  in the latter situation, that tag might even have to be userName+portfolioNumber

this seems... not ideal.  I have not been able to isolate the correct secret google search that reveals the standard way to do this - feel free to point me there as well.  (heck I prove to be bad at all drupal research for that matter)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For events which are a bit special and more cpmplex there is a lot of modules for doing things like that. I've used the signup module in the past and been happy about that.

For general marking of content, I think the flag module will get you where you want.

Comment: +1;  @Trass: The flag module is awesome and perfect for the kind of requirements you've listed.

Comment: Flag module!  you are a gentleman and a scholar!  @ NoParrots, you are a scholar and a prince.